# jQuery slice() Method select elements (first/last) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I want ask have nine elements as .projects ul class and i want ask how i can select the first three and the last three with jQuery slice method?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".projects").slice().css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eW6S5/176/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`:gt()` selects elements greater than passed value.

`:lt()` selects elements less than passed value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var n = 3;
    var len = $(".projects").length - (n+1);      
    $(".projects:lt("+n+"),.projects:gt("+len+")").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eW6S5/178/)

Comment: Thanks. And you have method to select the first three custom and the last three custom?

Comment: for first three margin 20px and the last three margin 0 px with this? not in one rule? with slice?

Comment: `$(".projects:lt("+n+")").css("margin","20px");`// first 3  `$(".projects:gt("+len+")").css("margin","0px");`// last 3